LlamaIndex Typescript to Javascript
How to convert LlamaIndex code written in typescript to javascript for use in a browser environment? I'm running into errors related to LlamaIndex imports. I'm converting using "tsc filename.ts".
node_modules/llamaindex/dist/type/types.d.ts:5:37 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@llamaindex/core/schema' or its corresponding type declarations.
  There are types at '/Users/kd/ragts/node_modules/@llamaindex/core/dist/schema/index.d.ts', but this result could not be resolved under your current 'moduleResolution' setting. Consider updating to 'node16', 'nodenext', or 'bundler'.

5 import type { EngineResponse } from "@llamaindex/core/schema";
                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/lru-cache/dist/cjs/index.d.ts:15:5 - error TS18028: Private identifiers are only available when targeting ECMAScript 2015 and higher.

15     #private;

The file does get converted but this line of code throws errors if I try to use it in a browser environment:
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var llamaindex_1 = require("llamaindex");

Error:
VM104:38 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at <anonymous>:38:23

This is the tsconfig.json:
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "ES2022",
      "module": "esnext",
      "moduleResolution": "bundler",
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "strict": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "lib": ["ES2022"],
      "types": ["node"],
      "outDir": "./lib",
      "tsBuildInfoFile": "./lib/.tsbuildinfo",
      "incremental": true,
      "composite": true
    },
    "ts-node": {
      "files": true,
      "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs"
      }
    },
    "include": ["./**/*.ts"]
  }

How should I change my approach so that it works in a browser environment? Any help would be appreciated!

Welcome to SO! your question is far away from entry level, please read How do I add a good question ... you are expected to share the code that you wrote, the input data, the expected result, the error messages that you get but all of it minimized to a bare minimum where your question can be reproduced. We are not a code writing or guessing service what you might have meant.

The default settings of tsc converts "export" statements that way to be "require"-ed in node js. You may try creating a tsconfig.json file to change that behavior, but I'm not sure if you'll get much functionality as according to https://github.com/run-llama/LlamaIndexTS browser support is limited.

Thank you for the clarification on the export statements. What do you suggest I can change in the tsconfig.json?
